# Why does my high score change no matter what?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im using unity to create a game. When the player dies the game over scene is loaded. No matter what happens, the high score is always set to the score value. Why?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HighScoreText : MonoBehaviour
{
    int score;
    int highScore;
    Text text;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        score = Score.score;

        if(score > highScore)
        {
            highScore = score;
        }

        text.text = highScore.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess a new HighScoreText is being created each time.  Can you show the code that uses this class?

Comment: probably because you reload the level and highscore is probably 0 at the start

Comment: @juharr Im not sure what you mean by the code that uses this class? The HighScoreText is not used in any other script.

Comment: @BugFinder I thought that since I dont initialise the highScore variable in Start(), that it is only called the once when the script is first called, and therefore the highScore variable should not revert back to 0

Comment: What will happen with your **Score** object? Will it be reset? Otherwise it could be that your **Score.score** property will be inreased without starting from 0!?

Comment: Start will be called IF.. you instantiate the object its on, either by actual code of instantiation, or, reload scene.. so if you reload the scene on death....

Comment: So when the player hits the play again button to go back to the game scene, the score is reset back to 0.

Comment: depends on how you go back to the game scene, but if you loadscene.. yes

Comment: @BugFinder but my highScore variable is not in my Start() function and therefore it should keep its value when the scene is reloaded. So does that not mean my code should work? Or does using LoadScene make it redeclare the variables again, even if they are not in start?

Comment: No it wont... the whole object is remade when the scene is reloaded.. ergo it will go back to 0

Comment: You need to make the HighScoreText class a singleton

Comment: @AnayTekstar every data member of the class will get reset when the object gets created.  everytime you reload the scene your objects in that scene get recreated, unless you have taken the necesarry steps to stop that,  from your script you have not.  Start doesnt replace the constructor of the class.  Start is the first method called when the scene starts.

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to understand what happens when you load a scene or even reload a scene.

It is also very important to understand that start IS not a constructor.  It is called the first frame a script is enabled before any update methods are called you can read more about that here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html

So let's analyze your problem, you load the gameOverScene, which starts by creating all your gameObjects and initializing your scripts.  This includes your highScoreText object(The gameObject with this script attached).  Now we have a thing called Scope.  It is possible to have 2 separate highScoreObjects, each of them would have their own values for highscore, since each value in your script is not global or static values that get shared.  Also an important thing to note, since this value is not static and is a member to that individual object, when the scene gets unloaded, all the objects in the scene get destroyed.  Which means the value you stored for highscore will get deleted.

So scene gets created, your objects get created with their default values if they arent static.  Scene gets destroyed all your objects get destroyed and so does all the values you stored on them.  So the solution would be to find a way to keep that value persistent through scenes... Seems like we have a few options from this per the comments above, and from what I have said about static values...

1 option is to make highscore static, now the value will not get destroyed when the scene changes... but it is shared across all highscore options...

another option is to make a singleton, and the pattern in unity for a singleton is to typically have a gameobject marked with (DontDestroyOnLoad)  then in the start method detecting if this singleton existed if it does and it isnt me, destroy myself.  if it doesn't make it me.

Personally, since I dont know the full scope of your project, I would just store it in the class you have already made called 'Score' make it static,  make an accessor for it,  and a method to check if current score is greater then highscore then return for example:

```
class Score {
    public static int score;
    private static int highScore;

    public static void CheckForNewHighScore() {
        if(score > highScore)
        {
            highScore = score;
        }
    }

    public static int getHighScore()
    {
        return highScore;
    }
}
```

This will take care of the problem you have with losing information when reloading the scene, and keep the highscore...

With this you can also change your highScoreText class to something like this

```
public class HighScoreText : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text text;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Score.CheckForNewHighScore();
        int currentHighScore = Score.getHighScore();
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
        if(text != null) {

             text.text = currentHighScore .ToString();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Removed everything from here because... well if they are 
        // on the gameover screen their score shouldn't increase 
        // So no reason to keep reseting the value.
    }
}
```